# Request doesnt get the input field name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a project where I ndeed to sell user credits so users can buy merch with these credits. I have set up the stripe API to charge the users when they buy coins but when I try to pass the quantity that the user selects at the function below it doesn't work and the credits don't update. It does not show an error either, the payment goes through but the credits don't. Here is the controller code:

```
 public function pay(Request $request){
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
        try{
        $charge = Charge::create([
            'amount' => Cart::total() * 100,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'description' => 'test product',
            'source' => request()->stripeToken
        ]);
        Session::flash('success', 'Purchase successfull. wait for our email.');

        Cart::destroy();



        $credits = UserCredit::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $qty = $request->get('qty');
        $credits->amount = $credits->amount + $qty;

        $credits->save();

        Mail::to(request()->stripeEmail)->send(new \App\Mail\PurchaseSuccessful);

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Session::flash('failure', 'Purchase failed. please try again');
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

And here is the input where the user chooses the number of credits he wants to buy

```
<td class="product-quantity">

<div class="quantity">
<a href="{{ route('cart.decr', ['id' => $pdt->rowId, 'qty' => $pdt->qty ]) }}" class="quantity-minus">-</a>

<input title="Qty" name="qty", id="qty" class="email input-text text" type="text" value="{{ $pdt->qty }}" placeholder="1" readonly>

 <a href="{{ route('cart.incr', ['id' => $pdt->rowId, 'qty' => $pdt->qty ]) }}" class="quantity-plus">+</a>
      </div>

</td>
```

Do I have a logic error here. Are there other ways to do this?
Thanks in advance

Here is the submit

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.add') }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="quantity">
                                <a href="#" class="quantity-minus quantity-minus-d">-</a>
                                <input title="Qty" class="email input-text qty text" name="qty" id="qty" type="text" value="1">
                                <a href="#" class="quantity-plus quantity-plus-d">+</a>
                            </div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="pdt_id" value="{{ $product->id }}">

                            <button class="btn btn-medium btn--primary">
                                <span class="text">Add to Cart</span>

                                <span class="semicircle"></span>
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

The decr and incr functions

```
 public function incr($id, $qty){
        Cart::update($id, $qty + 99);
        Session::flash('succes', 'Product qunatity updated.');

        return redirect()->route('cart');
    }

    public function  decr($id, $qty){
        Cart::update($id, $qty - 100);
        Session::flash('succes', 'Product qunatity updated.');

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

the form that points to pay controller

```
 <span style="float: right;">
                                                            <form action="{{ route('cart.checkout') }}" method="POST">
                                                                  @csrf
                                                                  <script
                                                                      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                                                                      data-key="pk_test_51IxqgMAlDT4eyPaP6esPvqCU1oG6GFqtF9ZhOb0oytpk2WnYA99OcD0kqnNs8VOEm18CpV9k7wYI5VGMwRFXahp700RezbuxMS"
                                                                      data-amount="{{ Cart::total() * 100 }}"
                                                                      data-name="BetGame"
                                                                      data-description="Buy our products"
                                                                      data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                                                                      data-locale="auto">
                                                                  </script>
                                                            </form>
                                                      </span>
                                    <div>
```

Comment: you should paste the cart controller incr and decr code here.and in html where you let the user submit qty.I didn't see any submit

Comment: You seem to be using a already made solution. Are you sure you are not supposed to use the `Cart` singleton (?)?

Comment: @nay i added the submit above

Comment: @nitrin0 im using a shopping cart package https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/wiki/Maintained-Forks

Comment: @KejviXhelilaj I'm not familiar with it but it was indeed my impression. But my suggestion stands: have you tried to fetch the quantity information from `Cart` (before destroying it of course)?

Comment: @nitrin0 I thought of that, but could not get around to how to do it. I used Cart::content->qty for example but did no good

Comment: @KejviXhelilaj i think you're looking for the `count` method (https://github.com/hardevine/LaravelShoppingcart/blob/master/src/Cart.php#L227).

Comment: @nitrin0 I feel that returns the quantity of items in a cart not the quantity of a single product or am i wrong

Comment: @nay did you see the code, any ideas

Comment: Probably @KejviXhelilaj. But note that `contents()` returns a collection (of items in the cart). If you iterate through it and/or locate the item you want you can `->qty`.

Comment: @KejviXhelilaj There are still something not right.First the form action not point to pay controller.so I don't know what things will post to pay controller.Second,if you already have quantity in session.why not use it from session

Comment: @nay i will update the code to show you the checkout blade. How to use it from sessions,can u help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks to @nitrin0 suggestion above to use count function of the cart package

```
$qty = Cart::count();
            $credits->amount = $credits->amount + $qty;
            $credits->save();
```

Comment: finally.I just want tell you use cart to get qty.glad you solve it

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an input value for any HTTP verb use:

```
$qty = $request->input('qty');
```

Comment: Tried that but same result